# Cannot Excute multiple commands/arguments using process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process

I cannot seem to excute multiple commands in a process, first of all they require admin rights which i have done using "runas". I want all the commands to run under one process.

I Have tried many different ways in which to get this to work However nothing seems to be working. I have tried to put the commands together into one string. i have added spaces with slashes. i have used "&" also "&&". i have put them in the ProcessStartInfo also have added them as an argument. Nothing seems to be working

these are the two arguments well commands i want to start:

netsh interface ip set address Ethernet static 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 1

netsh interface ip set dns Ethernet static 0.0.0.0 primary

I have hidden the IP's with 0's

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface ip set address Ethernet static 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 1");
p.StartInfo = psi;
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
psi.Verb = "runas";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Im hoping someone can help me fix this issue and help me run multiple commands through one process

Thank you

Comment: Try `var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c echo foo && echo bar");`

Comment: From `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /?` */win32manifest:<file>          Specify a Win32 manifest file (.xml)* set your manifest file to `requireAdministrator`.